# Email in outlook comes in different order when sent from SMTP server using Java mail API

Tags: java, linux, bash, outlook, smtp

I am using java mail API to send emails regarding the progress of my Java Application . The emails are being sent by an SMTP server to different email id 's configured in a property file . The email we use is an outlook client . 
At some times , 2-5 emails are send in 1-2 seconds . When we try to see the emails from outlook in a browser or outlook app , the order of the email gets changed than  from which I have sent them my code .

Why is that emails comes in different order in outlook .

I even tried the same exercise with `mail` command as shown below

```
echo "test mail content" | mail -s "test mail subject"  dileep@abc.com
```

When I send many emails from console using the above command , then also the order of the email was wrong .So below are the questions .

- Is there any parameter I can use to promptly send emails
- Is it   require any changes on the SMTP server I am using

Comment: The order depends on the sort settings of your current view. Assuming they are sorted based on the Sent date, it is perfectly legal for Exchange to stamp the sent date on a message out of order when it comes to submission.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Can you explain the part   "sort settings of your current view" .What I am using is a java code to send emails using an smtp server .Even though I am sending the emails in correct order , it is not  coming in correct order in Outlook . I am thinking like , smtp server is sending in wrong order , or not sending immediately .

Comment: "Coming in correct order" where? The Sent Items folder? The Inbox folder of the recipient?

Comment: in Inbox folder of recipient , it comes in wrong order .

Comment: SMTP transmission process is asynchronous,The SMTP server is free to send your earlier emaisl later. Unless you separate your messages sufficiently (10s of seconds?), they can be delivered out of order. There is nothing you can do about that.